# Should I create multiple Dockerfile's for parts of my webapp?

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment

I cannot get the idea of connecting parts of a webapp via Dockerfile's.

Say, I need Postgres server, Golang compiler, nginx instance and something else.

I want to have a Dockerfile that describes all these dependencies and which I can deploy somewhere, then create an image and run a container from it.

Is it correct that I can put everything in one Dockerfile or should I create a separate Dockerfile for each dependency?

If I need to create a Dockerfile for each dependency, what's the correct way to create a merged image from them all and make all the parts work inside one container?

Comment: *docker-compose* is what you seek.

Comment: Does it mean I have to have each dependency as a separate Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

The current best practice is to have a single container perform one function. This means that you would have one container for ngnix and another for your app.. Each could be defined by their own dockerfile. Then to tie them all together, you would use docker-compose to define the dependencies between them.

Answer (score 0):

A *dockerfile* is *your* docker image. One *dockerfile* for each image you build and push to a docker register. There are no rules as to how many images you manage, but it does take effort to manage an image.

You shouldn't need to build your own docker images for things like Postgres, Nginx, Golang, etc.. etc.. as there are many *official* images already published. They are configurable, easy to consume and can be often be run as just a CLI command.

Go to the page for a docker image and read the documentation. It often examples what mounts it supports, what ports it exposes and what you need to do to get it running.

Here's nginx:

https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

You use *docker-compose* to connect together multiple docker images. It makes it easy to *docker-compose up* an entire server stack with one command.

How to use *docker-compose* is like trying to explain how to use *docker*. It's a big topic, but I'll address the key point of your question.

> Say, I need Postgres server, Golang compiler, nginx instance and something else. I want to have a Dockerfile that describes all these dependencies and which I can deploy somewhere, then create an image and run a container from it.

No, you don't describe those things with a *dockerfile*. Here's the problem in trying to answer your question. *You might not need a dockerfile at all!*.

Without knowing the specific details of what you're trying to build we can't tell you if you need your own docker images or how many.

You can for example; deploy a running LAMP server using nothing but published docker images from the docker hub. You would just mount the folder with your PHP source code and you're done.

So the key here is that you need to learn how to use *docker-compose*. Only after learning what it can not do will you know what work is left for you to do to fill in the gaps.

It's better to come back to stackoverflow with specific questions like "how do I run the Golang compiler on the command line via docker"